# Анимация display:none и opacity:0 для div блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как одновременно совместить `display:none` и `opacity`.

В данном случае, нужно, чтобы при наведении на `<label>` присвоить `<div>` блоку(который находится внутри `<label>`) `opacity:1` и `display: block`; Если курсор убрать с этого `<label>`, то, соответственно, этому `<div>` блоку присвоить `opacity:0` и `display: none`.

Проблема заключается в том, что используя `opacity`, `div` блок становится невидимым, но на странице он есть. И при наведении курсора на это невидимое поле оно становится видимым:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы текстовая подсказка появлялась при наведении исключительно на выбранный на круг, чтобы при наведении на невидимый `<div>` блок он не становился видимым как на картинке.

Спасибо!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".radio-toolbar").on('mouseenter', '.color_label', function(event) {

    $(this).find('.tooltip').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 100);

  }).on('mouseleave', '.color_label', function(event) {
    $(this).find('.tooltip').animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 100);

  });
});
```

```css
.radio-toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 130px;
}
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.radio-toolbar label {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #939393;
}
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
.color_label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tooltip {
  margin: 0px 0px 13px 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
}
.tooltip_top {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}
.tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(24, 80, 120, 0.6);
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-toolbar">

  <label for="radio1" class="color_label" style="background-color: #FAFBFB">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="all">
    <div class="tooltip tooltip_top">
      <i class="tooltip-arrow"></i> Белый
    </div>
  </label>

  <label for="radio2" class="color_label" style="background-color: #C1C1C1">
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="false">
    <div class="tooltip tooltip_top js-tooltip">
      <i class="tooltip-arrow"></i> Серый
    </div>
  </label>

  <label for="radio3" class="color_label" style="background-color: #FDE910">
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="true">
    <div class="tooltip tooltip_top js-tooltip">
      <i class="tooltip-arrow"></i> Желтый
    </div>
  </label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В JQuery есть функция `show/hide`, которая прячет и открывает блок используя указанный стиль:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".radio-toolbar").on('mouseenter', '.color_label', function(event) {
    
    // Проверяем, не навёл ли пользователь на tooltip
    if(!$(event.target).hasClass('tooltip')){
      // Функцией stop останавливаем все предыдущие анимации, показываем элемент и делаем его плавное появление
      $(this).find('.tooltip').stop().css('display', 'block').animate({opacity: 1}, 100)
    };
    
  }).on('mouseleave', '.color_label', function(event) {
    
    // Функцией stop останавливаем все анимации и плавно делаем прозрачным блок
    $(this).find('.tooltip').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 100);
    
    // Скрываем после всех анимаций
    $(this).find('.tooltip').queue(function() {
      $(this).css('display', 'none');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.radio-toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 130px;
}
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.radio-toolbar label {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #939393;
}
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
.color_label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tooltip {
  margin: 0px 0px 13px 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
}
.tooltip_top {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}
.tooltip {
  display: none; /* Скрываем блок */
  opacity: 0; /* И делаем его прозрачным */
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(24, 80, 120, 0.6);
  pointer-events: none; /* Убрать полное взаимодействие мыши с tooltip */
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-toolbar">


  <label for="radio1" class="color_label" style="background-color: #FAFBFB">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="all">
    <div class="tooltip tooltip_top">
      <i class="tooltip-arrow"></i> Белый
    </div>
  </label>


  <label for="radio2" class="color_label" style="background-color: #C1C1C1">
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="false">
    <div class="tooltip tooltip_top js-tooltip">
      <i class="tooltip-arrow"></i> Серый
    </div>
  </label>


  <label for="radio3" class="color_label" style="background-color: #FDE910">
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="true">
    <div class="tooltip tooltip_top js-tooltip">
      <i class="tooltip-arrow"></i> Желтый
    </div>
  </label>

</div>
```

Comment: А если бы анимация была бы чуть посложнее, но включала бы появление и скрытие? Имхо это не решение проблемы....... Кстати баг:  если навестись на кружок а потом быстро поставить курсор на подсказку, то она исчезнет и сразу появится..

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так лучше?

Comment: так возникает иногда другой баг: если навестись на кружок, а потом на подсказку (или в сторону), а потом обратно на кружок, то подсказка не появится xD

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, всё, и это пофиксил )

Comment: Умничка. А теперь было бы неплохо описать подробно про эти баги и что сделалось, чтоб их не было))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ты задолбал :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, написал в комментариях к коду

Comment: Ну а что, я вот, как несмыслющий человек, который придет из поиска, да и хотя бы просто читающий разделы для повышения знаний просто не пойму что было не так и что нужно чтобы было так. А вдруг я буду делать что-то и столкнусь с такой же ситуацией. Что делать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, почитать учебничек про JS )

Comment: Тогда зачем нужен этот ресурс и все его отвечающие участники? Репкой померится? Потешить самолюбие?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я обычно это и делаю, судя по моим ответам :D Я расписал в комментариях всё

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да

Comment: а слабо без jQuery справиться?

Comment: @VostokSisters, вызов принят

Comment: @VostokSisters, слишком хлопотно ) Анимацию пока сделаешь на одном js...

Comment: @Yuri, мне просто интересно, можно ли без js совмещать дисплей нон и опасити? По-моему нельзя, я как-то пробовал.  Я тоже начал, но тут у чувака по всей видимости нужда в отслеживании клика через jQuery, так что не стал делать ответ.

Comment: @VostokSisters, с помощью анимации CSS по-моему можно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52981/discussion-between-vostoksisters-and-yuri).

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `fadeIn()` и `fadeOut()`, также не забудьте останавливать анимацию при помощи `stop()`. И еще надо будет подчистить стили: по умолчанию надо убрать у тултипа нулевую непрозрачность и добавить `display: none`.

UPD: чтобы избежать мигания при наведении на тултип, добавил к нему псевдоэлемент с высотой, равной промежутку между кружком и тултипом.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".radio-toolbar").on('mouseenter', '.color_label', function(event) {

    $(this).find('.tooltip').stop(true, true).fadeIn(100);

  }).on('mouseleave', '.color_label', function(event) {
    $(this).find('.tooltip').stop(true, true).fadeOut(100);

  });
});
```

```css
.radio-toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 130px;
}
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.radio-toolbar label {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #939393;
}
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
.color_label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tooltip {
  margin: 0px 0px 13px 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(24, 80, 120, 0.6);
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.tooltip:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
}
.tooltip_top {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-toolbar">


  <label for="radio1" class="color_label" style="background-color: #FAFBFB">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="all">
    <div class="tooltip tooltip_top">
      <i class="tooltip-arrow"></i> Белый
    </div>
  </label>


  <label for="radio2" class="color_label" style="background-color: #C1C1C1">
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="false">
    <div class="tooltip tooltip_top js-tooltip">
      <i class="tooltip-arrow"></i> Серый
    </div>
  </label>


  <label for="radio3" class="color_label" style="background-color: #FDE910">
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="true">
    <div class="tooltip tooltip_top js-tooltip">
      <i class="tooltip-arrow"></i> Желтый
    </div>
  </label>

</div>
```

Comment: у вас тоже баг как я описал в комменте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622850/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B8%D1%8F-displaynone-%D0%B8-opacity0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-div-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0#comment867937_622854)

Comment: точно, поправил и это.